# If a PhD position I applied for and didn't hear back from is removed and relisted, does this mean I was rejected?

Tags: phd, application, rejection

I just wanted to know your opinion about an issue. I have contacted the supervisor of a research project for doctoral student position and I was encouraged to apply. By the way my experience really fits the position.

I applied through the online application platform and after that I didn't receive any mail regarding my status. Then the post for this research position was removed last week and I just saw that the position post is online again. 
I think that they are not interested in me, because if they did I think they would have contacted me and not put the post again to search for applicants.
What do you think? Am I rejected?

Comment: Hey, welcome to academia. I don't mean any snark by that--that's the way it's done for some inexplicable reason. If you eventually apply for a faculty position, expect most of your applications to go into a black void, never to be answered. It's really annoying, and I wish people would at least use a form letter for closure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reposting a search does not mean that all the applications received so far are unsuitable. It often means that they have not received the volume of applications they expected/wanted and are worried, without having necessarily looked at the applications, that they might have missed qualified applicants.

Given you applied on line and never got a status update, it is always reasonable to ask if everything is okay. Given the position has been reposted, it is worth asking if you need to resubmit your application. Sometimes HR and electronic systems do not carry applications over from one position to the next.

Comment: actually they received my application because they asked me to send originals of diplomas. I'll ask that if i need to apply again.

Answer (score 7):

If the project supervisor encouraged you to apply previously, it should be fair to inquire about the status of your application. Maybe just ask for a confirmation that they received it.

Answer (score 1):

If the professor is not responding, why not just give the professor a phone call or drop by their office to talk?  It may be best to first set up an appointment for the phone call or office visit.